# Extracting a Specific Cell from a Table in a Web Page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-table

I am having a subroutine which works well in extracting table from a webpage. I am looking forward to extract a particular inner text in table precisely **(3rd Column and 5th Row)** in excel worksheet.

The code is as mentioned below:

```
Sub Extracttable()

Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim oRow As Object, oCell As Object
Dim data

y = 1: x = 1

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
.Open "GET", "https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2020-02-07", False
.Send
oDom.Body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

With oDom.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
ReDim data(1 To .Rows.Length, 1 To .Rows(1).Cells.Length)
For Each oRow In .Rows
For Each oCell In oRow.Cells
data(x, y) = oCell.innerText
y = y + 1
Next oCell
y = 1
x = x + 1
Next oRow
End With

Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(data), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
End Sub
```

I need to extract a specific cell as mentioned above.

Any help pertaining to the same will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant you just want the single value then:

```
Sub Extracttable()

Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim oRow As Object, oCell As Object
Dim data

y = 1: x = 1

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
.Open "GET", "https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2020-02-07", False
.send
oDom.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Debug.Print oDom.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows(5).Cells(2).innerText

End Sub
```

Both `.Rows` and `.Cells` are zero based so I figured you are interested in the actual 6th row > Units per USD for AUS.

Comment: Thanks JvdV ,

It works fine for me, but I need to extract that value to Sheet 1 . Please suggest for the same. 

Thanks

Comment: @DipreetSingh. Then specify a cell. Its very basic VBA knowledge' `Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = ....`. Even better is to specify a sheet through its name: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells...etc...`  if this answer helped then consider to accept it as such. Click the checkmark to the left of it.